# Python: raw image data to grayscale

Tags: python, numpy, reshape, grayscale, imshow

I have raw image data stored in a text file, in a format like this and I would like to make it a 2D array and convert it to grayscale.

```
0
0
0
0
24
243
227
223
224
225
227
228
228
```

What I would like to do is take this data, convert it to grayscale, and display the image. My plan is to use numpy...I have this working in matlab, but I'm having difficulty implementing it in python

I have tried to do the following:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from pylab import *

ROWS = 144
COLUMNS = 175
raw_image = []

lines = [line.strip().split(',') for line in open('CAMERA.txt')

for i in lines:
    raw_image.append(i)

mat_image = np.zeros((ROWS, COLUMNS), dtype = int)

for i in rage(ROWS):
    for j in range(COLUMNS):
        mat_image.itemset(i, j, raw_image[(i-1)*COLUMNS + j])

plt.gray()
axes = app.image.add_subplot(111)
self.im = Image.fromarray(mat_image)
axes.imshow(self.im)
app.imageCanvas.draw()
```

I've also tried doing:

```
np.reshape(raw_image, ROWS, COLUMNS)
```

However neither of these approaches work. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I read your question but I do not fully understand what your problem is, so maybe you can clearify that (What are the problems? Post a stack trace). Maybe it will help if you read the following [page](http://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html). Its a tutorial to plot images (also grayscale) with matplotlib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program below could do what you want if I correctly interpreted what you want to do ;-)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


if __name__=='__main__':

    rows = 144
    columns = 175

    camera_image = np.loadtxt(r'path/to/filename')
    if(not camera_image.size == rows * columns):
        raise Exception('Size mismatch!')

    my_image = np.reshape(camera_image, (rows, columns)) / 255.0

    figure = plt.figure()
    axes = figure.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

    axes.imshow(my_image)

    plt.show()
```

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty simple method of going from text integers to PIL image that works for me:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

ROWS = 50
COLUMNS = 50

# greyValues.txt is 2500 RGB values 0-255 one per line
arr = np.genfromtxt('greyValues.txt', dtype=np.int8)

arr.shape = (ROWS, COLUMNS)

img = Image.fromarray(arr, 'L')
img.show()
img.save("textimage.jpg")
```